# Looking for a Facebook-like photo manager

Tags: facebook, media-manager

I am looking for a program that lets me store metadata about my pictures and make albums of them as well as presenting memories to me when pictures have an anniversary. I don't want to post the pictures publicly on Facebook though. Would also prefer that it be free and be able to handle unlimited photos if possible.

Comment: This is built right into Apple Photos… so I presume you're asking about Windows software? Please edit to clarify.